# If Bayesian optimization is used for hyperparameter tuning, do we still need to perform cross validation?

Tags: machine-learning, bayesian-optimization

Given the hyperparameter tuning is sampled from the probability distribution, is it still necessary to perform cross validation?

Comment: Why shouldn't it?

Answer (score 1):

Cross validation is not necessary, but some sort of *validation* is. Because, you're going to measure your model's performance on the validation set. One way or another, you'll choose some set of hyper-parameters, train your model and test on the validation set. Bayesian hyper-parameter tuning enables you to choose this set more cleverly (especially better than random search which uses no heuristics at all), without exploring the entire space via some sort of exhaustive grid search.